# BadRarFile error opening a rar file protected with a password

Tags: python, rar

iam trying to open an encrypted password and i know the correct password, and its says that :
`rarfile.BadRarFile: Failed the read enough data: req=592 got=0`

here is the code iam using

```
from rarfile import RarFile
with RarFile('daisy.rar', 'r') as myrar:
    myrar.extractall(pwd='@Daisy_Cloud')
```

but iam getting and error rarfile.BadRarFile, and i think its related to encrypted file names when encrypting the rarfile because the same code works when i don't encrypt filenames

Comment: Please [edit] to add more details. Are you using [rarfile](https://pypi.org/project/rarfile/)? Which version? Using which backend utility? Is that utility able to decrypt the file outside of Python?

Comment: Note that rar is not a well-defined format -- there's a reference implementation written in C that's under free-to-use terms, but it's under a license that prevents people from making changes, _including_ fixing bugs, so anything built on top of that reference implementation is buggy and insecure; and anything built without reliance on the reference implementation (with its onerous license) is based on reverse engineering and liable to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rarfile](https://pypi.org/project/rarfile/) python module.

```
import rarfile

# Open the RAR file
rar = rarfile.RarFile("path/to/password-protected/file.rar")

# Set the password for the RAR file
rar.setpassword("password")

# Extract all files from the RAR file
rar.extractall()
```

The `rarfile` library requires external tool like :
`unrar (preferred), unar or bsdtar`
You can install unrar using system package manager
`sudo apt-get install unrar`

Assuming you have a debian based distro.

Comment: Please explain how this avoids a BadRarFile error. (Does `setpassword` do a different thing from the `pwd=` argument in the `extractall` invocation?)

Comment: iam getting this error when i use your code :
rarfile.BadRarFile: Failed the read enough data: req=592 got=0

i told you whenever i encrypt my rar file and i specify encrypt files names with it on windows i got this problem